# Como organizar uma aplicação Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

Tendo em vista que o express não tem nenhuma funcionalidade integrada de "autoload", qual seria a melhor estrutura ou boilerplate para seguir em um projeto monolítico de grande porte? e como cria-la?

Comment: Você tem um padrão de projeto que prefere usar?

Comment: express-generator seria a melhor forma. Há uma estrutura completa, focando apenas em no desenvolvimento!